# How can I install wxpython correctly on OS X 10.11?

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, wxwidgets

I am trying to install wxpython 3.0.1.1 on my OS X 10.11.3, python 2.7 . I have tried many ways but still was not successful.

--the method explained in wxpython main page failed even with changes to security and using command line install.

finally I tried to do it by brew and when I print the brew list I have:

```
$ brew list
  gdbm      libtiff     readline    wxpython
  jpeg      openssl     sqlite
  libpng        python      wxmac
```

so that in:

```
$ brew install wxpython
Warning: wxpython-3.0.2.0 already installed, it's just not linked
```

how can I make the link? if I type `pip list` I get other modules which all work. but `brew list`.. it seems it does not work!!

still when I want to import wx, it says:

```
>>> import wx
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named wx
```

would you please  help me install it correctly! there are many solutions proposed and I have tried some but still no results!!I really need it.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**<sub>Warning: wxpython-3.0.2.0 already installed, it's just not linked.</sub>**

To create the link referenced by Homebrew:

```
$ brew link wxpython
```

If that doesn't work try running:

```
$ brew doctor
```

Then follow the instructions/recommendations; On newer versions of OS X you might need to change the permissions/ownership for `/usr/local` in order to allow homebrew to create the link:

```
sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local
```

then try `brew link wxpython` again.

Comment: by `$ brew link wxpython`  ....  I get: 
`Linking /usr/local/Cellar/wxpython/3.0.2.0... Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-osx_cocoa`.... and by ... `brew doctor`   after many warnings finally finished...but what are the further instructions you mentioned??!

Comment: @AMN, try doing `sudo brew link wxpython` to have super-user privileges. This maybe will fix the "permission denied" error

Comment: @Alessiox: `Error: Cowardly refusing to 'sudo brew link'`
`You can use brew with sudo, but only if the brew executable is owned by root.
However, this is both not recommended and completely unsupported so do so at
your own risk.`

Comment: @AMN: I think with `OS X 10.11` you either have to use sudo (not recommended as said), or change the permissions on the `/usr/local` directory so that brew can write to it, etc.

Comment: @AMN, indeed. I agree with @l'L'l. Seems like you have to change the `/usr/local` permissions. Try doing `sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local` and try re-linking again

Comment: @Alessiox @ I'L'I : finally it worked correctly by changing permission and `brew link`ing.Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try installing it through command line rather than pip.

sudo installer -pkg /path/to/wxPython.pkg -target /

Also please dont forget to turn off the gatekeeper during installation.

Comment: `$ sudo installer Desktop/wxPython3.0-osx-cocoa-py2.7.pkg/ -target /`
`installer: invalid option Desktop/wxPython3.0-osx-cocoa-py2.7.pkg/
Usage: installer [-help] [-dominfo] [-volinfo] [-pkginfo] [-allowUntrusted] [-dumplog]
                 [-verbose | -verboseR] [-vers] [-config] [-plist]
                 [-file <pathToFile>] [-lang <ISOLanguageCode>] [-listiso]
                 [-showChoicesXML] [-applyChoiceChangesXML <pathToFile>]
                 [-showChoicesAfterApplyingChangesXML <pathtoFile>]
                 -pkg <pathToPackage>
                 -target <[DomainKey|MountPoint]>`

Comment: would you please tell me why the path has error?sorry but it may seem a stupid question...